# Trigger middleware within the call method using Python and uWSGI

Tags: python-3.x, mod-wsgi, uwsgi, wsgi

I was confused at one point when I was developing an application to run on wsgi - more specifically on uwsgi.

After building my example application:

```
class MyCustomApp():
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','application/json')])
        return "a".encode('utf-8')

application = MyCustomApp()
```

Everything works perfectly as expected. 
**I use a class instead of a method, I need to use it for other reasons.**

Now let's get to the problem. I am using middleware called beaker and if I replace my application with:

```
application = SessionMiddleware(MyCustomApp(),options)
```

Everything is normal, **but I don't want to modify my call**, despite for the sake of study and understanding.

I would like to do the following:

```
class MyCustomApp():
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','application/json')])
        ...
        here i want to implement SessionMiddleware without modify
        application = MyCustomApp()
        ...
        return "a".encode('utf-8')

application = MyCustomApp()
```

But nothing I try, my middleware replaces my environment with its defaults. I wish they could guide me to understand and try to implement keeping the logic above.